# Searching for illustrated children's book with a distinctive hat central to a medieval story

Tags: story-identification, illustrated-story

Growing up in the 70's, I had a favorite illustrated children's fairy tale concerning a hero who defeats a chameleon-like monster in a forest. At the crucial moment of the conflict, the hero's cap falls down over his eyes protecting him from the monster. In my memory, the story is something like the Firebird ballet with a princess to rescue or a magical item to retrieve. I can't recall the name of the hero or any other details of his quest. I distinctly remember the hero wearing a "bycocket" or Robin Hood cap. I'd appreciate any advice on the title or author of this book.

Comment: In what sense was the monster chameleon-like? (Did it change colours?) Why did the hero's cap falling down over his eyes protect him from the monster? (Seems like that would be a hindrance, if anything.) Also, is there definitely princess in this story, or are you unsure about that?

Comment: And is the creature chameleon-like in terms of looking like a lizard? Independently moving eyes? Ability to change the color of their skin according to their emotion?

Comment: Needing protection from the monster's gaze sounds more like a basilisk.

Comment: Or the [Ravenous Bugblatter Beast of Traal](https://hitchhikers.fandom.com/wiki/Ravenous_Bugblatter_Beast_of_Traal).

Comment: My recollection was the monster had the appearance of a giant chameleon. I seem to remember a coiled tail and the eyes of a chameleon. However, I haven't seen the book in many years, so my memory may be faulty on these details.

Comment: I mentioned a princess only in connection to the story of the Firebird which I am also very fond of. There may have been a princess in the story in question, but I simply don't remember. I feel that the character names and perhaps the architecture was Slavic.

I recall the illustrations were pen and watercolor with desaturated colors. They had a style akin to this first illustration by Tolkien: https://news.artnet.com/art-world/jrr-tolkien-art-morgan-library-1449088

Comment: I thought of the connection to a basilisk, too. The cap over the hero's eyes is stuck in my memory. It may have been to prevent the hero from turning to stone or from being stunned.

The hero's cap was the part that is distinctive in my memory. I remember the shape being like a bycocket or Robin Hood cap. But it was worn backwards relative to how Robin Hood is portrayed, either during the whole story or during the scene he encounters the monster.